# Xcode 4.3.1 texturetool missing?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-lion, opengl-es-2.0

I just updated to the new version of Xcode, I've tried downloading both the command line tools and graphic's tools from the developer portal. Where is it gone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry for only half an answer, but you can find the command line tools by starting Xcode, going into Preferences, choosing the Downloads Tab and clicking "Install" on "Command Line Tools". I'm also missing texturetool though :-/

Edit: Look and you shall find, texturetool is actually there, just hidden. If you have Xcode installed in /Applications, it's at;

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool

Comment: I've tried downloading both the command line tools and graphic's tools from the developer portal.

Comment: @Nico: Did you follow Joachim's instructions? He didn't advise you to download anything from the developer portal.

Answer (score 2):

The `texturetool` utility is still packaged with Xcode (I am using Xcode 11 beta 5 at the moment), however it's only part of the `iphonesdk` sdk (and no other) and you can run sdk tools using the `xcrun` command line tool:

```
~ xcrun -sdk iphoneos texturetool
Usage error

Usage: texturetool [-hl]
       texturetool -c <reference_image> <input_image>
       texturetool [-ms] [-e <encoder>] [-p <preview_file>] -o <output> [-f <format>] <input_image>

       first form:
         -h       Display this help menu.
         -l       List available encoders, individual encoder options, and file formats.
       second form:
         -c       Compare <input_image> to <reference_image> and report differences.
       third form:
         -m       Generate a complete mipmap chain from the input image.
         -s       Report numerical differences between <input_image> and the encoded image.
         -e       Encode texture levels with <encoder>.
         -p       Output a PNG preview of the encoded output to <preview_file>. Requires -e option.
         -o       Write processed image to <output>.
         -f       Set file <format> for <output> image.
```

Note: You probably need the Xcode command line tools installed too:

```
~ xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the last posters answer. 
1. open /Applications/TextEdit.app ~/.bash_profile . 
Add the following to bash_profile
2. # setting path for texture tool iOS
PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
3. Save the file and close the console window.
4. reopen and command line tools and type texturetool